# Batch script to find and delete all folders named PGP Corporation

Tags: batch

> for /f %%i in ('dir /a:d /s /b *PGP Corporation*') do echo rd /s %%i

So this is what I have and it works great for one word folders e.g. c:\crap, but if I were to user "c:\my crap" all it will give me is c:\my I have tried quotations as seen below.

> for /f %%i in ('dir /a:d /s /b *"PGP Corporation"*') do echo rd /s %%i

But there was no love an ideas would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `delims` parameter. Something like this :

```
for /f "delims=*" %%i in ('dir /a:d /s /b "PGP Corporation"') do echo rd /s %%i
```

This produces this output on my system :

> rd /s C:\stack\PGP Corporation\my crap

ps : in my case `%%i` does not work, i had to use `%i`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the directory path, in the `rd` statement, in quotes:

```
for /f %%i in ('dir /a:d /s /b "PGP Corporation"') do echo rd /s "%%i"
```